# How to validate and clean data prom external xml in django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want to load data from untrusted external rss source (via feedparser) and validate/clean it the same way as django would with the form.
How to do it?
Should i just create form for it and populate it from data from feed?
If yes how to do that?
Normally it would be something like this:

```
f= MyBogusForm(request.POST)
```

I got my data in the dict like this one

```
myDict={
'title':'some title',
'date' : <time.struct_time>,
'author' : 'John Doe'
'content' : 'string with HTML that needs to be converted to text only'
}
```

the date and content could be a problem, if not this i cold possibly use

```
form = MyBogusForm(myDict)
if form.is_valid():
(...)
```

Answer (score -1):

Extract data to dict from XML file using parser and then pass this data dict to form.